# How to avoid "FragmentManager is already executing transactions" during commitNowAllowingStateLoss

Tags: android

I have the following piece of code. It will crash, when I

1. Press home to put app into background
2. Show notification on notification bar, when stock alert happens.

If user pressed on the notification, the app will be launched via the following intent

```
Intent appIntent = new Intent(context, JStockFragmentActivity.class);
appIntent.putExtra(JStockFragmentActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_BEST_WATCHLIST_INFO, bestWatchlistInfo);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, appIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

---

However, crash will occur in the following function

```
public void removeRetainInstanceFragments() {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    fm.beginTransaction().remove(this.realTimeStockMonitorFragment).commitNowAllowingStateLoss();

    fm.executePendingTransactions();

    ...
}
```

I'm using support library **25.3.0** with target SDK 25.

I will get the following crash. **It never happen before I migrate to current new support library**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1956)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1980)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
    at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.WatchlistFragment.removeRetainInstanceFragments(WatchlistFragment.java:879)
    at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.JStockFragmentActivity.selectActiveContent(JStockFragmentActivity.java:1306)
    at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.HomeMenuFragment.selectCurrent(HomeMenuFragment.java:925)
    at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.HomeMenuFragment.selectCurrentWithPreviousSaved(HomeMenuFragment.java:915)
    at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.JStockFragmentActivity.handleHomeMenuRowInfoFromExtrasIfPossible(JStockFragmentActivity.java:1231)
    at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.HomeMenuFragment.handleHomeMenuRowInfoFromExtrasIfPossible(HomeMenuFragment.java:389)
    at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.HomeMenuFragment.onResume(HomeMenuFragment.java:289)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2238)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1346)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2914)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:223)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:509)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:498)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:172)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6351)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1388)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Any idea what mistaken I did, which causes this problem?

Comment: Have you tried with [`setAllowOptimization(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setAllowOptimization(boolean))?

Comment: I had tried that. It doesn't help.

Comment: Did you find a solution other than using an earlier support library?

Comment: Same problem here with new support library.